# Resistance measurement: Agilent 34401A vs. Fluke 179

Tags: resistance, multimeter, instrumentation

I was attempting to measure isolation resistance between the output of an isolated DC/DC converter to machine chassis. I was somewhat surprised to see a large difference in measurement between a 6 1/2 digit DMM in 2W mode and a normal handheld one, 75 k\$\Omega\$ vs. 500 k\$\Omega\$. The measurement of the 34401A was even a bit erratic, landing on either 75 k\$\Omega\$ or 120 k\$\Omega\$, depending on from where the autoranging starts. The equipment under test contains differential and common mode capacitors and chokes, and as I understand it, the 34401A may use some sort of pulsed measurement, although I'm not sure exactly how it's implemented. When I measure a normal through hole 1 M\$\Omega\$ resistor, the two instruments are quite close.

Should I return my new "used, but calibrated" Agilent 34401A to the dealer and file a warranty claim, or rather learn how to use a multimeter?

PS: In case anyone was wondering, I made sure to measure such that the TVS diodes were in reverse bias, i.e. + measurement lead to power output and - measurement lead to chassis.

Comment: Isolation resistance is probably outside the measuring range of both multimeters and both try to make some sense with the capacitance. Try measuring a capacitor in resistance mode.

Comment: Just tried a 0.47u ceramic capacitor. After charging up, both instruments go to OVLD/OL as expected.

Comment: Now try that with a 1MΩ across it.  Adding L/C to a resistance measurement can give weird results depending on how the R measurement is being performed.  Could be that one meter attempts near-DC measurement, while the other is pulsed... of which the capacitance influences more.  Doubt anything is mis-calibrated.

Comment: Was the DC-DC converter powered during this measurement? Or was anything else connected to it (other than the meter) connected to any kind of power source?

Comment: @Sphero, good question, I forgot to mention this. The equipment was unplugged from the supply and completely off. Also, the equipment grounding and Ethernet was disconnected for the measurement (to prevent us from measuring any "false" paths through the mains/network grounding)